# Field in schema-browser screen in Solr admin Console

Tags: solr

[image]

Above is the screenshot attached for the schema browser screen for a particular index. The field is **brandName**.

Field type is defined as following:

```
<fieldType name="wc_keywordText" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Indexed, Tokenized, stored ... etc are the properties of field. Can anyone explain what it signifies for the rest like Schema and Index(Colored in red box).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this is describing where these properties for a field are coming from. Initially, when you have an empty index, this screen contains only properties row, which lead me to the intuition, that **properties** are take from **schema.xml**

**Index** row appears only after I added some documents to the Solr index. For example, my **id** field isn't stored and than, I do not have information in this row for this field (pay attention to the *(unstored field)* text)
[image]

And the row **Schema**, here is a bit tricky to me. I was thinking that this has something to do with Schema API, like when you create field/update field via REST calls, than this **Schema** row will represent. However, it turns out different, if I modify the field type (for example add support for docValues for the field, which didn't have it), you will have this screen.[image]

It leads me to idea, that Schema row actually represents what is happening in the schema, while properties have the current one. Remember, I've **add** support for docValues. Which leads me to the idea, that if you have **ClassicIndexSchemaFactory**, than Schema and properties row should be the same, if you have **ManagedIndexSchemaFactory**, that these rows could be different.