# Schema vs Index vs Properties in solr schema screen

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr6, solr-schema

[image: solr admin panel schema view]

what does it mean if something has tick mark for "Indexed" in "Schema" but not for "Indexed" in "Index"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Field in schema-browser screen in Solr admin Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128970/field-in-schema-browser-screen-in-solr-admin-console)